What does this writing mean on my Irish passport stamp?
I recently traveled to Amsterdam via Dublin, and when going through Irish customs, I told them I would just be going into the city for the day, and would be continuing on to Amsterdam that evening. On my stamp, the border agent wrote "12 hrs" which I assume means that I would be in the country for just the one day, and also "∞ IT AMS" which I'm more confused by. I assume AMS is for Amsterdam, but what of the rest? I've included a picture.


My guess is IT stands for In Transit

IT means "In Transit". You've been admitted for 12 hours based on your claim that you're transiting to Amsterdam, and the writing is intended to signal to the immigration officer doing exit checks to confirm that you've complied.

Ireland doesn't do border control on exit; your answer is otherwise correct

Neither does the UK where I've had similar notes on stamps. But a) they can, and b) the stamp is an evidence of status.

There was no exit check but I have an Amsterdam stamp for that night on the next page so that proves compliance. What of the infinity though?

@DanishChef No idea, I'd suggest emailing bmu@justice.ie attaching the image if you're curious about that
